# How can a pandas DataFrame histogram plot get month or day orders right?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, histogram, pandas-groupby

I want to have a set of functions that can plot a histogram of a variable in a DataFrame for bins that might correspond to days, months or hours. When I try to do this I end up with plots that have the days or months listed alphabetically in the horizontal axis when they should be listed temporally. How should this be done?

My MWE code is as follows, and is intended for a Jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (17, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-02", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-04", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-07", 1],
             ["2017-07", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-12", 1]
         ],
         columns = ["datetime", "score"]
    )

df["datetime"]     = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
#df["hour"]         = df["datetime"].dt.hour
#df["weekday_name"] = df["datetime"].dt.weekday_name
df["month_name"]   = df["datetime"].dt.strftime("%B")
df.index           = df["datetime"]
del df["datetime"]
df.head()

# ----------

def histogram_hour_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a day-long histogram of counts of the variable for each hour. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `hour` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "hour" in df.columns:
        log.error("field hour not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "hour")[variable].count()
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

def histogram_day_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a week-long histogram of counts of the variable for each day. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `weekday_name` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "weekday_name" in df.columns:
        log.error("field weekday_name not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "weekday_name")[variable].count()
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

def histogram_month_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a year-long histogram of counts of the variable for each month. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `month_name` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "month_name" in df.columns:
        log.error("field month_name not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "month_name")[variable].count()
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

# ----------

histogram_month_counts(variable = "score", df = df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to `import calendar` and `reindex` your results with `caleandar.month_name` from your groupby-count statement like this:

***Note*** from [calendar documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html)

> calendar.month_name An array that represents the months of the year in
>   the current locale. This follows normal convention of January being
>   month number 1, so it has a length of 13 and month_name[0] is the
>   empty string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import calendar
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (17, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-01", 1],
             ["2017-02", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-03", 1],
             ["2017-04", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-05", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-06", 1],
             ["2017-07", 1],
             ["2017-07", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-08", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-09", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-10", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-11", 1],
             ["2017-12", 1]
         ],
         columns = ["datetime", "score"]
    )

df["datetime"]     = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
#df["hour"]         = df["datetime"].dt.hour
#df["weekday_name"] = df["datetime"].dt.weekday_name
df["month_name"]   = df["datetime"].dt.strftime("%B")
df.index           = df["datetime"]
del df["datetime"]
df.head()

# ----------

def histogram_hour_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a day-long histogram of counts of the variable for each hour. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `hour` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "hour" in df.columns:
        log.error("field hour not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "hour")[variable].count()
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

def histogram_day_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a week-long histogram of counts of the variable for each day. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `weekday_name` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "weekday_name" in df.columns:
        log.error("field weekday_name not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "weekday_name")[variable].count()
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

def histogram_month_counts(df, variable):
    """
    Create a year-long histogram of counts of the variable for each month. It is
    assumed that the DataFrame index is datetime and that the variable
    `month_name` exists.
    """
    if not df.index.dtype in ["datetime64[ns]", "<M8[ns]", ">M8[ns]"]:
        log.error("index is not datetime")
        return False
    if not "month_name" in df.columns:
        log.error("field month_name not found in DataFrame")
        return False
    counts = df.groupby(by = "month_name")[variable].count().reindex(calendar.month_name[1:])
    counts.plot(kind = "bar", width = 1, rot = 0, alpha = 0.7)

# ----------

histogram_month_counts(variable = "score", df = df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! Following from your months implementation, I found that `.reindex(calendar.day_name[0:])` works for the days implementation.

Answer (score 0):

counts = df.groupby(by = "month_name")[variable].count()

You are grouping by the month_name, which is likely where sorting is happening also.

I believe you need to sort by the index since that is where your datetime data is.